# create an array of class instances in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new to java.

I want to have an array of a class whose length may vary during run time

code:

```
class Num
{
  ......
  ......
}
```

if Num is my class , how will i create new instances. My current code is pretty similar to:

```
Num n[ ];
int length=0;
.
.
.
n[length++]=new Num();
```

from this code I'm getting error :

```
"Uncompilable source code - variable factors might not have been initialized"
```

Comment: Just a heads-up—I don't think that error you're getting at the bottom has anything to do with your array creation syntax. Do you have a variable named `factors` declared but not initialized?

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for this purpose.

```
ArrayList<Num> myListOfNum = new ArrayList<Num>();
```

and then keep adding the objects of `Num` as and when required.

```
Num num1 = new Num();
myListOfNum.add(num1);
Num num2 = new Num();
myListOfNum.add(num2);
```

EDIT:

And to access you can use the `get()` method along with the specific index.

```
Num tempNum = myListOfNum.get(indexGoesHere);
```

Comment: how can i acces each element from ArrayList??

Comment: @sebastian-thomas `List` supports both serial access (using `iterator` or `listIterator`) as well as random access (using `get`, `set`, `add`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first create the array itself, before you are trying to set the elements in it.

```
 Num[] n = new Num[SIZE];
```

Note that `Num n[];` is just declaring a variable of type `Num[]` with the identifier `n`.

Note however, that in java - arrays are of fixed lengths. If you are looking for a variable length array, an array is probably not what you need. @KazekageGaara suggested an alternative - for this purpose.

Comment: i am nt sure of size..it may vary during run time

Answer (score 2):

Use the Java Collection

`List` will be good if **sequence** is more important.

`Set` if **uniqueness** is important

`Map` when **key-value pair** is important

```
List<MyClass> arrList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

arrList.add(mobj1);
arrList.add(mobj2);
arrList.add(mobj3);

for(MyClass m : arrList){

      // m is the Values of arrList stored in

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is by using ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Num> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add elements to the ArrayList
    numList.add(new Num());
    numList.add(new Num());
```